# Как называются жители города Ухань?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, грамматика, названия, вопрос

Как называются жители города Ухань? Прекрасно понимаю, что не "уханцы". Для рассказа очень нужно. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А как Вам удалось прекрасно понять? И даже намекнуть на уханчан? Я за уханцев. Обтекаемо: житель/и города Ухань.

[Род и склонение топонима Ухань в русском языке является предметом споров и не имеет однозначного решения. Часть источников рекомендует склонять этот топоним по третьему типу склонения как существительное женского рода (типа **Казань**), однако в реальности он чаще употребляется как топоним мужского рода, изменяющийся по второму типу склонения (типа **Суздаль**). В качестве нейтрального варианта, обходящего проблему выбора рода и склонения, рекомендуется аппозитивная конструкция, позволяющая не склонять топоним: в городе Ухань.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C)

Казань - казанцы, казанец, казанка;
Суздаль - суздальцы, суздалец, суздалянка.

---

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ К РАЗМЫШЛЕНИЮ

1. [Можно ли называть жительницу Казани казанкой и никого этим не оскорбить?](https://e-kazan.ru/news/show/43475)
2. Грамота.ру - Вопрос № 257590:

> Добрый день!
>
> Буду признательна за ответ на вопрос: как называются жители Суздаля? А
> один житель? А жительница?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Словари фиксируют несколько вариантов: ***суздальцы, суздалец*** и
> ***суздальчане, суздальчанин, суздальчанка***.

---

[В Китае разъяренные **уханцы** пытаются снести блокпост полиции, который поставила соседняя с Уханем провинция, чтобы тестировать на коронавирус.](https://www.facebook.com/Ray.net.ua/posts/2946988288699147)

---

[Фoнeтичecкий paзбop cлoвa "**yxaнeц**"](https://fonetic.textologia.ru/definit/uhanec/?q=1048&n=150255)

---

[Лишенные возможности нормально передвигаться по городу, **уханцы** приобретают продукты с доставкой на дом.](https://belsat.eu/ru/news/uhan-posle-40-dnej-karantina-fotografii/)

---

[В Ухани — эпицентре распространения эпидемии — местные власти ужесточили режим карантина. Теперь **уханцы** не могут свободно передвигаться по городу, поскольку им запрещено покидать свои кварталы без особой надобности.](https://www.9tv.co.il/item/10241)

УХАНЧАНЕ не встречаются как класс.

Comment: Просто я в рассказе написала "явно не уханец", а мне моя подруга заявила: Если так при китайцах кого-то назовешь, то убьют на месте. Правильно - чжоане. Теперь понимаю, что она скорее всего перепутала с названием жителей Гуаньчжоу. Понятно, кого китайцы убьют:)

Comment: П.С.1) Про УХАНЧАН я даже не задумывалась. Думала, по провинциям называют: Хубэйка, хубэец и т.д.

Comment: 2) Как называется жительница Уханя?

Comment: 3) Ухань- мужской род, как Кинель и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

> Прекрасно понимаю, что не "уханцы".

Тут вопрос-то в том, как называют - или как должны.

Если вопрос о точном передаче китайской фонетики, то он не стоит. Это просто не возможно. Возражу только автору комментария "убьют на месте", что китайцы всё понимают - и никого не убивают. Привыкли.

С другой стороны понятно, что никакое именование по провинции (а такое в китайском действительно практикуется чаще, чем в русском) не заменит название собственно жителей города.

Вот с грамматикой - тут не подарок.  Если предположить, что Ухань - м.р., то катойконим логично производить как ***уханьцы*** по образцу Суздаль -суздальцы.
Если Ухань - женского, то - ***уханцы*** мягкость теряется: Казань-казанцы.

Однако, все дело упирается в то, что никакой "мягкости" в китайском в помине нет. **НЬ** используется для транскрипции обычного звука **n**, в то время как **Н** соответствует носовому **ng**. Так что и уханцы представляется не совсем ошибкой, даже если принять, что Ухань - ж.р.

Answer (score 0):

behemothus, вы как раз таки правы. В китайском нет мягкого звука, соответсвенно "УханЬ" это неправильное произношение. Стоит просто посмотреть на английскую транскрипцию - Wuhan. Однако не станут же русские говорить "Юхан", вот и перефразировалось в "Ухань". Это как Пекин - вроде бы "Бейджинг", но в русском перефразировалось в "Пекин". Моя логика такова: если в английской транскрипции оно звучит как "Юхан", значит это мужской род. Но жители городов называются "Уханцы". Тогда посмотрим на склонение по падежам: Ухань - и.п.Уханя - р.п., Уханю - д.п., Ухань - в.п., Уханем - т.п., о Ухане - п.п. Если бы это был женский род, то: Ухань - и.п., Ухани - р.п., Ухани - д.п., Ухань - в.п., Уханью. - т.п., о Ухани - п.п.
Яйцо - и.п., яйца - р.п., яйцу - д.п., яйцо - в.п., яйцом - т.п., о яйце - п.п. И там, и там окончания "у-ю", "ем-ом" и т.д. сходятся. Значит(внимание): Ухань - СРЕДНИЙ род. В китайском нет склонения названий городов, в английском - просто "Im from Wuhan". Соответсвенно, здесь два варианта:

1. Уханец, уханка, уханцы.
2. Уханчанин, уханчанка, уханчане.

Пример:

В городе Ухань;
23-летняя уханчанка взломала Пентагон; Уханцы снесли памятник в Кишиневе.

Правильно так, как в примерах.

Answer (score 0):

*Правильная* русская транскрипция собственных имён (в данном случае: **Ухань**) основывается не на попытках звукоподражания китайскому, а на стандартной (условной) фонетической записи (в начале прошлого века принята система Палладия), в которой различаются китайские передненосовое и задненосовое  "н", соответственно "нь" (**n** в официальной латинизированной транскрипции) и "н" (**ng**). Как бы ни произносилось написанное в английских текстах **Wuhan**, эта запись совпадает со стандатной (принятой в Китае с 1956 года) латинизированной фонетической транскрипцией названия города, которой строго соответствует русская запись "**Ухань**" (**n** -> **нь**). В силу этого она и **правильна**. Чтобы разобраться в производных словах, обратимся к Розенталю:

> [как исключение пишутся с мягким знаком]
> прилагательные, образованные
> от некоторых иноязычных географических наименований: куэнь-луньский,
> сычуаньский, тайваньский, тянь-шаньский, **уханьский**, так же гдыньский.

http://old-rozental.online/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3666

То есть наблюдается тенденция к устойчивому воспроизведению китайского слогового окончания "нь" имени собственного, по крайней мере в прилагательных. Должно ли оно утрачиваться в существительных? В современной журналистике (хотя она редко даёт хорошие примеры), обкатавшей тему Уханя (газета МК и др.), находим "**уханьцев**", а гуглом по книгам находятся "**сычуаньцы**". Поэтому я тоже не вижу оснований для "уханцев", независимо от приписываемого городу грамм. рода (в текстах доминирует мужской; женский ассоциировался бы с "лоханью" и "тмутараканью" и выглядел бы непочтительно).

Answer (score 0):

УхаНЬ, СычуаНЬ, ТайваНЬ — не знаю как это называется в русском, но в румынском это род "neutru". Пишем в мужском роде, склоняем в женском. То же самое и здесь, только наоборот — пишем в женском, склоняем в мужском. Сказать "уханцы" — всё равно что сказать "кинелцы". Кинельчане, уханьчане. И никак по-другому.